# Thread waiting for resources

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety

I have an assignment in which I have 2 threads that use a shared singleton class instance the stores a list of resources.
when a thread receives an event he tries to acquire resources using the shared instance. A resource is acquired by making a boolean field that says if he's free to false.
The problem is that if one thread is using a resource that is needed by the other thread then what will the other thread does while waiting for the second thread to finish? all I could think about is a while loop that doesn't stop until he's acquired all of the required resources, but it's busy wait and I try to think of a different way.

```
public class Thread1{
    private SharedObject sharedObject;
    public void acquire objects(List<Integer> indexes){
        for(int i=0;i<indexes.size;i++){
            sharedObject.acquire(indexes[i]);
        }
    }
}
 // I have another Thread which is implemented the same way
public class SharedObject{
   private List<SomeObject> someObjects;
   public synchronized void acquire(int index){
      someObjects[index].acquire();
   }
}
public class SomeObject{
   private boolean isFree = true;
   public void acquire(){
      isFree = False;
   }
}
```

So my problem is what to do if one of the resources is already in use while I try to acquire them

Comment: It sounds like your are trying to reinvent Condition Variables. Have a look at [`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) and the other classes in [java.util.concurrent.locks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html). The package docs for [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) may also be of interest.

Comment: You can also use [`wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) and [`notify`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) inside `synchronized` code.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the singleton class with a synchronized 'boolean resourceWait(), a method that must be called by threads requiring any set of resources, and 'resourceRelease()' that must be called when a thread is finished with some set of resources.  It also needs an, initially empty, 'waiting' list of thread instances that are waiting for resources.

Declare a thread class that exposes a public list of resources and a 'resourcesAvailable() method that signals a private semaphore.

Inside the 'resourceWait'singleton lock, a thread can check if it can get all its resources immediately and, if so, flag them as in-use, exit the synchro method with 'true' and run on.  If the thread cannot get all it's resources immediately, it can load itself into the waiting list, exit the synchro method with 'false' and so wait on its private semaphore.

When a thread calls release, it sets the resources flags to 'free' and iterates the 'waiting' list, looking for threads that can now get all the resources they need. If one is found, it sets the 'in-use' flags for the resources of the waiting thread, calls 'resourcesAvailable' on the waiting thread, (signaling its semaphore and so setting it ready/running), and exits the syncro.

No busy-wait looping, no deadlocks, easily extended/modified, easily debugged.